# Set a bitmap to NetworkImageView

Tags: android, networkimageview

I am creating Imageviews dynamically and displaying it. But i faced reloading problem when scroll so i decided to use NetworkImageView but here i am not able to set the bitmap. It is not showing any error but it is not displaying any images. 
Below my code...

```
final NetworkImageView imageView = new NetworkImageView(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150,
            200);
    params.weight = 1;
    //imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setMaxHeight(200);
    imageView.setMaxWidth(150);
    // bitmap =//
    // BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),R.drawable.ic_menu_folder);
    // Log.i("Bitmaps Counts", String.valueOf(pos));
    /*    comment all this...
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {


                bitmap = downloadImage(tempValues.getItemAbsolutePath());


            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                }
            });

        }
    }.start();*/
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,new LruBitmapCache(1000000));
     mImageLoader.get(tempValues.getItemAbsolutePath(),
            ImageLoader.getImageListener(imageView,
                   R.android.defaultimg,
                   R.android.errorimg));

    layout.addView(imageView);
```

downloadImage code..

```
/* unused method
      private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }*/
```

errorlog

05-12 19:11:13.971: E/AndroidRuntime(11177): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-7325
05-12 19:11:13.971: E/AndroidRuntime(11177): Process: com.dar.app, PID: 11177
05-12 19:11:13.971: E/AndroidRuntime(11177): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -350
05-12 19:11:13.971: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
05-12 19:11:13.971: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.get(DiskBasedCache.java:117)
05-12 19:11:13.971: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):    at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:100)

Comment: I am new to android at least please guide me

Comment: please check my updated code and what i am doing is i am creating it dynamically and passing to holder. below code i am not understanding

Comment: It worked?If so, increase my answer. Thanks

Comment: No i am getting confuse..If i use Imageview when i scroll the list it will re downloading the image again and image position are changing.

Comment: if you are not working with object yes.
what you can do is work with image cache. (http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html)

or in your list of objects storing the reference image.

Comment: Ok can u tell me how to stop that image re downloading when i scroll, can i post my adapter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can use volley image downloder

it easy
default img is set...loader request for image ..
if image found using url it will set ..or if error it will set error image..this way you'll inform about the error on loading img

```
 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
 ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,new LruBitmapCache(1000000));
 mImageLoader.get(<img-url>,
                ImageLoader.getImageListener(<imageview-object>,
                       R.drawable.defaultimg,
                       R.drawable.errorimg));
```

Comment: @Mister if this edited code work..then i'll update my answer ..to accept the answer of this question...thats found easy for other in future

Comment: R.android.defaultimg    for android i am getting error

Comment: because i am implementing in adapter

Comment: put some images for default and error...and name it as i've used on code...and change "R.android" with "R.drawable"..also i've updated the code

Comment: OMG thanks a lot :) but if i scroll two three times it will close the app

Comment: 05-12 18:50:59.121: E/AndroidRuntime(7857): java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -350

Comment: java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException: -350 at which line ? and whats the code?

Comment: 05-12 19:08:14.491: E/art(10712): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 795174765 byte allocation with 1897829 free bytes and 122MB until OOM"

Comment: 05-12 19:11:13.971: E/AndroidRuntime(11177):  at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)

Comment: set heap size large inside <application> tag...using android:largeHeap="true" for outofmemoryerror...

Comment: try increasing cache size from 1000000 to 80000000

Answer (score 1):

**FINAL CODE**

```
public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap image;
    private LinearLayout linear;

    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView imageView, LinearLayout linear) {
       this.imageView = imageView;
       this.linear = linear;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            image = null;
        }
        return image;
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
            linear.addView(imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

**Now call in your code:**

```
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150, 200);
params.weight = 1;
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
imageView.setMaxHeight(200);
imageView.setMaxWidth(150);

new DownloadImageTask(imageView, layout).execute(tempValues.getItemAbsolutePath());
```